# Find the distribution parameters

Tags: self-study

On STAT101 your assessment is based on:
Final Exam 50%
Learn based on-line assessment 30%
Assignments 20%
Consider three random variables $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ which respectively represent the exam, on-line assessment total and assignment scores (out of 100%) of a randomly chosen student. Assume that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent (this is clearly not true, but the answers may be a reasonable approximation).
Suppose that past experience suggests the following properties of these assessment items (each out of 100%): $E \left ( X \right ) = 61$, $sd(X) = 20$, $E(Y) = 72$, $sd(Y) = 22$ and $E(Z) =65$, $sd(Z) = 24$.

a) Find the distribution parameters, $E(T)$ and $Var(T)$, for the total mark, $T$, where:
$T = 0.5X+0.3Y+0.2Z$.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints that will hopefuly guide you to the answers.

The expectation $E(T)$ can be obtained using the [linearity properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties) of the expected value.

The variance $\mbox{var}(T)$ can be obtained using the expression of the [variance of a sum of random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) and using the independence of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ to determine the value of the covariance terms that appear.